# Como não matar um subprocesso aberto por outro arquivo em python?

Tags: python-2.7, script

Eu gostaria de a partir de um script em python rodar um programa que eu desenvolvi em python também. No entanto eu gostaria de encerrar o meu script, mas não o programa que abri por ele.

Estou abrindo o meu programa por um subprocess dessa forma:

```
self.davros_p = subprocess.Popen(
        [python_path, "-m", "meu_programa", "start"],
        stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'),
        stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w')
    )
```

Ambos rodam perfeitamente, no entanto quanto eu mato o meu script, eu acabo matando junto o meu programa.
Teria alguma forma de fazer com que o meu programa não fosse finalizado junto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente isso é um problema no Windows. Quando um signal é dado para matar o script, esse signal é repassado para o subprocesso, que é o meu_programa.
Um forma de resolver isso é incluir "creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP" a lista de parâmetros do Popen.

```
self.proc = subprocess.Popen(
    [python_path, "-m", "meu_programa", "start"],
    stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'),
    stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w'),
    creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP,

)
```

O Windows repassa o signal a todos os processos do mesmo grupo, assim incluindo o creationflags você cria um novo grupo para o subprocesso do meu_programa e ele não será morto quando se deseja matar apenas o script.